# android: how to dynamically change layout of navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using one activity for the entire app but multiple fragments to represent different screens. I also have a navigation drawer to go with it. I would like to change the navigation drawer layout based on whether the user is logged in or not. How do I dynamically change the layout of the navigation drawer. Is it possible to have different layout xml for navigation drawer, one for logged in view and one for anonymous user? If so, how to do it?

Second question: Is there a better way to do it for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You should wait until you know whether the user has logged in or not to create the Navigation Drawer.

Typically you will want a LoginActivity which is the launch screen, and your MainActivity for when the user logs in.

Regardless of whether the user logged in or "skipped" login, you will have this information at the time you create you Navigation drawer.

Comment: Well, I do want to show the drawer even for users not logged in as there are some common screens the users can navigate to even when they are not logged in. Not all functionality is available for users not logged in. So I want to show the drawer for all users, logged in or not. However, I want to show different things depending on he's logged in or not.